# WCF Rest Error Handling

Tags: wcf, rest, error-handling

I'm having a mind blowing problem using WCF 4.0 RESTful  service. I am trying to make  a rest service that will return, in case of an error, a xml document  describing the problem
ex :

```
    <ErrorHandler>
        <cause>Resource not  available</cause>
        <errorCode>111103</errorCode>
    </ErrorHandler>
```

In order to make this i've created a default REST service using the  template provided by visual studio 
Here  is my service  Class :

```
public class Service1
    {
        // TODO: Implement the collection resource that will contain the SampleItem instances

        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "")]        
        public List<SampleItem> GetCollection()
        {
            // TODO: Replace the current implementation to return a collection of SampleItem instances\
           // throw new WebException("lala");
           throw new WebFaultException<ErrorHandler>(new ErrorHandler { cause = "Resource not  available", errorCode = 100 }, System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            //return new List<SampleItem>() { new SampleItem() { Id = 1, StringValue = "Hello" } };
        }

        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "", Method = "POST")]
        public SampleItem Create(SampleItem instance)
        {
            // TODO: Add the new instance of SampleItem to the collection           
            return new SampleItem() { Id = 3, StringValue = "59" };

        }

        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "{id}")]
        public SampleItem Get(string id)
        {
            // TODO: Return the instance of SampleItem with the given id
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "{id}", Method = "PUT")]
        public SampleItem Update(string id, SampleItem instance)
        {
            // TODO: Update the given instance of SampleItem in the collection
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "{id}", Method = "DELETE")]
        public void Delete(string id)
        {
            // TODO: Remove the instance of SampleItem with the given id from the collection
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
}
```

As you can see from the code above i am throwing a WebFaultException in the  GetCollection method. that should put in the body of  the response a "ErrorHandler"  object. 
Here is how my ErrorHandler class looks like :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace WcfRestService1
{
    [DataContract]
    public class ErrorHandler
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int errorCode { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string cause { get; set; }

    }
}
```

The crazy thing is that this thing works but it down't :)). What i'm trying to say is that  visual studio is   giving me an error saying that the WebFaultException is not caught by the user code :| and it suspends my app. If i  press continue   everything works as it should. 
Here are some pictures describing my problem:

First step in fiddler :
[First Step](http://i130.photobucket.com/albums/p245/dreamer_prime/Step1.png)

Next  Visual Studio's error: [Visual Studio Error](http://i130.photobucket.com/albums/p245/dreamer_prime/Error.png)

Finally After  pressing continue   everything  works :

It makes no sense to me  and i have no idea why this thing is happening and  how to fix it :P. I've searched the web  for days  trying to find a solution  with no luck.  I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate

Best Regards  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is wrong here. You are debugging, an exception is thrown, it breaks, you continue and it works as it should.

I suspect you have set the exception handling option (Ctrl+Alt+E) to break when exceptions are thrown. ("Thrown" in the options) This will cause break whenever exception is thrown regardless it is handled.

Exceptions that are thrown in WCF operations will be handled by the WCF runtime and if they are faults, they will be sent back as such so that channel is not faulted.

Now with regard to sending back an XML, you can just send string representation of the XML using `WebFaultException<string>`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It's  still not clear to me why  VS 2010 is reporting that exception as unhandled. Isn't that exception caught by the  WCF runtime ? From what i understand, the exception should be caught by the runtime and the and the "Cause" object will be serialized  and sent back to the client with the specified http code. The strange thing is that vs 2008  didn't behave like this. I used to report errors by throwing a  Web ProtocolException and everything   was fine (Except the fact that the client wouldn't recieve a xml). After i  upgraded to vs 2010 this happened.

Comment: I never worked with 2008 so I would not know but I would not too much hung up on this. As long as your website works it is good. But as I said, look at your VS settings by pressing Ctrl+Alt+E.

Comment: I will do that . But i would like a more portable solution.  I'm not the only one working on that project and and asking everyone  in my team to use this workaround isn't that viable :)