# Exception handler in a WCF REST service

Tags: wcf, rest, c#-4.0

I would like to create an exception handler in a WCF REST service. For Client recesse this exception in a simple way. I found many implementations using SOAP IErrorHandler for WCF, but none for REST. Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using [WebFaultException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd989924.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

the exception information is provided in response message. Usually (in HTTP GET for REST), a result is expected as XML/JSON. In case of any error the error message is places instead of REST URI result.

http://www.robbagby.com/rest/effective-error-handling-with-wcf-rest/

[WCF Rest Error Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626334/wcf-rest-error-handling)

Answer (score 1):

`IErrorHandler` also works for WCF REST services, although you may need to know about how a non-SOAP (e.g., JSON) message is mapped inside the WCF `Message` object. The example at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/07/wcf-extensibility-ierrorhandler.aspx shows an error handler used to format responses to a JS client (in JSON).